# Assigning value to text, and finding sum in single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking to add value to text in a table, and then add those values together for a pricing sheet.

For example, if I have cell B1 containing a string such as "ABCD", I'd like to assign a value to each character and then find the sum. Say in this example A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4, I'd like the new cell to output "10" (sum of 1+2+3+4).

Edit: Using ABCD for an example seems to be a poor choice. On my actual pricing sheet, one of the cells contains '8205512AS'. For this particular cell, I'm looking to separate a price for '8205' and '512AS'. Example, if '8205' = $5, and '512AS' = $7, I'm looking for the new cell to output $12

Comment: Does it need to be a function? Would a UDF (function created in VBA) work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked for a Worksheet Function, but here's a UDF you can use. (Call with `=substitute_and_sum(B1)`.

```
Function substitute_and_sum(ByRef cel As Range)

Dim i As Long
Dim subDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Set subDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

subDict.Add "8205", 5
subDict.Add "512AS", 7
subDict.Add "234", 3
subDict.Add "23", 4
subDict.Add "2", 5

Dim output As Long
Dim key As Variant
Dim tmpStr As String
tmpStr = cel.Value

Dim L As Long
If InStr(tmpStr, "512") > 0 Then
    L = 5
ElseIf InStr(tmpStr, "615") > 0 Then
    L = 12
End If

For Each key In subDict.keys
    If InStr(tmpStr, key) > 0 Then
        output = output + subDict(key)
        tmpStr = Replace(tmpStr, key, "")
    End If
Next key

If Right(tmpStr, 1) = "L" Then
    output = output + L
End If

substitute_and_sum = output
End Function
```

Note: I don't know how many replacements you have, but if there's some logic, try and place in 'descending' order...?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be what I need once I edit the code for my parts, but I'm getting a Compile Error: User-Defined type not defined, and it's highlighting both the "Function substitute_and_sum(ByRef cel As Range)" as well as "subDict As Scripting.Dictionary"

Comment: @RyanMurray - Make sure you have the Dictionary reference in VBA. Select Tools->Reference from the Visual Basic menu then place a check in the box beside “Microsoft Scripting Runtime”.

Comment: That works, thank you! Last question (hopefully), If I have a string rather than a single character, say I'm looking to input a line akin to 'subDict.Add "8116N", 89.6', am I able to do so? Or would I need to modify the above code to handle a string?

Comment: @RyanMurray - It should work, `subDict.Add "8116N", 89.6`

Comment: @RyanMurray - Just thinking, you *might* run in to problems if you want to replace `A` with say `1`, but then want to replace `ACD` with `9`.  (Since the loop goes one character at a time, it'll replace `A` in `ACD`,  and then look for `C` next...)  Just wanted to note in case that might be an issue.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if that will be an issue. I have strings like '8116' followed by '8146'. It still doesn't seem to like any strings however. I can have it output values for my single character add-ins, but it won't do anything for strings.

Comment: @RyanMurray - See my edit.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm now! I appreciate it Batman

Comment: ..Just when I think I'm all set, I've found one more thing that I can't seem to work around. Is there a way to give a character a different price depending on other characters in the string? ex) ' 8205512ASL ' where 8205 = 5, 512AS = 3. L in this case = 10, but if my string were ' 8205411ADL ', 8205 = 5, 411AD = 4, L would now = 15. My apologies for formatting, can't quite seem to get it right.

Comment: @RyanMurray is there any logic why `L` changes value?

Comment: the `L` stands for a component that goes into an assembly. Although the part that the `L` stands for remains the same exact piece no matter the assembly, the size of box it goes on determines which mounting kit we use. We don't have a separate code in our product codes for the mounting kit, so the only place for me to add that price in is in the `L` and dependent on the box size. I don't like it, but it's all I've got to go with. I can go into better detail if needed

Comment: @RyanMurray is `L` the only such letter/number that can change or might you have multiple such characters?

Comment: @RyanMurray - Also, will the `L` also only be at the end of the string? Also I would assume that you could have `1234LDL` and want `1234L` to be, say `9`, but have that lone `L` be something else?

Comment: `L` is the only character like this, and yes it will always be at the end of the string

Comment: I guess I'm looking to do something similar to
`For Variable L
If anyString contains '512', then let L = 5
If anyString contains '615', then let L = 12`  etc. etc. I'm just not very familiar with VBA, and very amateur at coding in general

Comment: @RyanMurray I'll tweak and update in a bit.

Comment: I found something that works for my purpose, although it's probably not ideal. Using a separate function that checks each cell in the list if it contains `L` and one of the components that changes the price (example `512`). If true, outputs a value (or in my case the price-adder) to a new cell. So at this point I have the part in cell A1, the price that your code outputs in B1, the price adder from my new code in C1, and my total sum in D1. So far seems to be working!

Comment: @RyanMurray - Glad you got it working!  I've made a tweak to account for the `If myString contains 512 then...`.  Note that this assumes you wouldn't have, say, 51261500L (where you have both `512` and `615` in the same string...Hopefully this helps?

Comment: That would work perfectly as well! Thanks a ton for all the help! Truly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always want to use this pattern `A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4...` and your strings just have characters in the range `[A-Z]` this will work:

`=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),1))-64)`

What's going on here:

1. `MID(B1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B1))),1)` loops through each character in `B1`.
2. [CODE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/code-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928) provides the numeric (ASCII) value of a character.  Since [ASCII values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) follow the pattern `A=65, B=66, ...` the CODE value is offset by subtracting 64.
3. [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753E75-9F68-4874-94AC-4D2145A2FD2E) sums the offset ASCII code values.

Things to watch for:

1. Lowercase values `[a-z]` will provide other values.  Depending on what you want to do, you could use [UPPER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UPPER-function-C11F29B3-D1A3-4537-8DF6-04D0049963D6) to avoid this.
2. You would need to remove any non-alphabetic characters (e.g., by using [REPLACE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181))

Comment: I had commented on another user's answer but he/she seemed to have deleted it. I explained my situation a little poorly in using ABCD. On my actual pricing sheet, one of the cells contains '8205512AS'. For this particular cell, I'm looking to separate a price for '8205' and '512AS'. Example, if '8205' = $5, and '512AS' = $7, I'm looking for the new cell to output $12

Answer (score 0):

If your text is easily predicted with perhaps one string to want a value for being the first 4 characters in the cell and the rest making a second viable string, you can use string functions to separate them, feed them into `VLOOKUP()` which would look them up in a table that has their correct values, then add those.

So one portion of the formula takes the left 4 characters and inserts them into a `VLOOKUP()` that locates them and reads over for the price, finding $5. Added to it is a second bit of formula just like it (the `RIGHT()` function perhaps, using the cell length minus the 4 characters for the first one to get the length, or perhaps using the same first 4 characters in a `SUBSTITUTE()` function that puts in "" for them effectively "subtracting text from text) that takes the remainder of the cell contents and does the same lookup finding $7. The result would be the $12 you seek.

If it is not easily predictable, there would be array functionality you could ride to a solution, but that's involved enough to need a concrete example to demonstrate with.